# How do I create a boolean column based on odd/even dates in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to create a boolean column in pandas such that odd days will give me True, and even days will give me False.

The dates are in the format of 2019-MM-DD, such as 2019-06-04.

2019-06-04 is an even day, so I want to get False from it
2019-06-03 is an odd day, so I want to get True from it

I was thinking something along the lines of

```
df['New Column'] = int(df['Date'].astype(str).iloc[0][8:]) % 2 == 1
```

But the code above will only return the boolean of the first row in ['Date']

How do I make it such that the index 0 will increment down the rows?

Comment: what you mean by odd date?you mean odd days?

Comment: @AnuragDabas Yes, odd day. so 2019-06-04 is an even day, which should give me False

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try via `day` attribute:

```
df['Date']=pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
#ensure that 'Date' column is of dtype datetime
df['New Column'] =df['Date'].dt.day%2!=0
#Finally check if the day is even or not
```

Comment: Thank you, this works. I will approve it in a few minutes